# Django charfield regex

Tags: python, regex, django, django-models

Consider a `Charfield` with a `max_length` of `5`.

I want to put `hours` and `minutes` in this `CharField` like `HH:MM`.

I don't want to use the `models.TimeField` as it stores the time, not the amount hours and minutes. I want my CharField to hold,

**Example:**

> 8:45 (8hrs and 45minutes) which is why I want to add a regex validator that makes sure that the number before the colon `:` is less than 24 and the number after it less than 60.

How would I do that in regex?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What have you tried? This is needing a pretty simple regex.

Comment: Yea I realized that but after you closed my question xD. I just didn't know how to look for it, but now I do. Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Regex for this would be:

```
^(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

- `^` matches the start of the input
- `0?[0-9]` matches `0` (optionally) followed by any number between `0` and `9`
- `1[0-9]` macthes `1` followed by any number between `0` and `9`
- `2[0-3]` matches `2` followed by any number between `0` and `3` (so we match between 20-23)
- the above three patterns are `OR`-ed (`|`) so any one of them would be matched
- then `:` matches literal `:`
- `[0-5][0-9]` matches any number between `0` to `5`, followed by any number between `0` and `9` (this would match the minutes 00-59)
- `$` matches the end of the input

---

But what you should do:

- create a new validator by inheriting from `django.core.validators.BaseValidator`
- override the `__call__` method, and in there do the validation there using `str.partition` and `int` conversion.

An example:

```
from django.core.validators import BaseValidator

class HourMinuteDurationValidator(BaseValidator):
    message = 'Some message'

    def __call__(self, value):
        cleaned_value = self.clean(value)
        hour, minute = cleaned_value.partition(':')

        try:
            hour, minute = int(hour), int(minute)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            raise ValidationError(self.message)

        if not (
            (0 <= hour <= 23) and (0 <= minute <= 59)
        ):
            raise ValidationError(self.message)
```

---

If you insist on using Regex, you can use the given Regex pattern with `django.core.validators.RegexValidator`.

Comment: That works just as fine as well. Good thing you included that. It would help other people that come here and don't want to use regex.

Comment: @AnthonyMartinez Regex is much costly than string operations. So if you can avoid it, do so. OTOH, if you have to use it, see if you have the option to compile it beforehand (`re.compile`), and if you have such option, save it in the highest available scope.

Comment: Ah! I see. I knew about the methods that go into regex but never really considered how costly it would be. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```py
charfield = models.CharField(verbose_name='...', max_length=...,
                 validators=[validators.RegexValidator(
                             r'^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$')]
```

Will match any HH:MM but not H:MM H:M